# Changing properties of source block for different states in a statechart

Tags: anylogic

I have a model in Main that looks like this:

[image]

The source block is set to uniform(4,8) hours in interarrival time.

1. When the statechart goes from "normalWeather" to "storm" I want source to stop injection
2. When the statechart goes from "storm" to "normalWeather" I want the interarrival times to come back to uniform(4,8) hours.

What is a suitable solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the source block to inject instead of interarrival time. Then add a transition of type `timeout` from `normalWeather` state to itself. Set the timeout as:

```
uniform(4,8)
```

And set the action as:

```
source.inject();
```

[image]

That way, as long as your agent is in the state normal weather, agent injections will occur at your desired rate.

Comment: Worked out brilliantly. Thanks for the thorough solution even though my problem formulation lacked a bit of information.